# Extracting coefficients of non-linear equation across categorical variable

Tags: r, apply, curve-fitting, nls, nonlinear-equation

This question appears to be off-topic because it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations, or it asks about obtaining datasets. You could try the support links we maintain or the Open Data site instead.

If you are asking about how to debug some code or carry out a task in a programming language, this is not an on-topic question. If you're asking about how to obtain data, that is not an on-topic question. If you feel your question is truly about statistics as described in the help center, please [edit] to clarify.

Closed 25 mins ago.

(Private feedback for you)

I am trying to extract the coefficients k1,2 and 3 from the equation:

```
Mt=M1exp(−k1⋅CDI⋅t)+M2exp(−k2⋅CDI⋅t)+M3exp(−k3⋅CDI⋅t)
```

where Mt is mass at time t, m1 is the initial labile carbon content (in %), m2 is holocellulose content, m3 is lignin content, and finally, CDI

is climate decomposition index (see below image).

I have managed to extract the coefficients from a single sight using the following code:

```
eqtn <- function(m1, k1, cdi, t, m2, k2, m3, k3){(m1 * exp(-k1 * cdi * t)+
                                             m2 * exp(-k2 * cdi * t)+
                                             m3 * exp(-k3 * cdi * t))}

nls(mass_remaining_percent ~ eqtn(scf_mean_initial, k1, cdi_mean, days_between, 
                                  holocellulose_mean_initial, k2, lignin_mean_initial, k3),
    start = list(k1 = 0.0007, k2 = 0.0005, k3 = 0.0001), data = a.3_pooled_data)
```

Does anyone know how I can apply this over categories of sight (field code) and extract the coefficients/ R2? I know that it needs splitting into many small datasets, then applying the model, extracting data and recombining but I can't figure out how to do it

Thanks in advance[image: Example of data]

I have just managed to write the above code, fitting the model to a singular line of code, I know that I can do this manually, fitting to many smaller datasets but it will take an age and I would like to learn how to do it using the apply family or the broom package.

Comment: I am not certain if it's an April fools thing but your first two paragraphs should not be in body of question. Did you copy/paste something incorrectly?

Comment: @Parfait The question was asked on CrossValidated before but they closed it because this is a question about how to use R, not about statistics.

Comment: @Bernhard, thanks. Strange, SO usually indicates if question was migrated from a different SE site unless OP re-posted and copied over the mentioned caption.

Comment: Please provide a small dataset – with `data.frame()` or dput()` because we can’t import your screenshot into R

Answer (score 1):

For coefficients, use either  [**`coef`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/coef) to return a vector or [**`summary.nls(...)$coefficients`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/summary.nls) to return a matrix which also includes t-stats and p-values on results of `nls()`. To run model by groupings, consider `by` (the object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`):

```r
eqtn <- function(m1, k1, cdi, t, m2, k2, m3, k3) {
    (m1 * exp(-k1 * cdi * t) +
     m2 * exp(-k2 * cdi * t) +
     m3 * exp(-k3 * cdi * t))
}

model <- mass_remaining_percent ~ eqtn(
    scf_mean_initial, k1, cdi_mean, days_between, 
    holocellulose_mean_initial, k2, lignin_mean_initial, k3
)

run_model_by_group <- function(sub) {
    results <- nls(
        model,
        start = list(k1 = 0.0007, k2 = 0.0005, k3 = 0.0001), 
        data = sub
    )

    return(summary(results)$coefficients)
}

# LIST OF COEFFICIENT MATRICES BY FIELD CODE
field_code_coefficient_matrices <- by(
    a.3_pooled_data,
    a.3_pooled_data$Field.Code,
    FUN = run_model_by_group
)
```